# Inno Setup type mismatch when assigning function return value to a string

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I have the following function in my Inno setup:

```
function GetSerialNumber(ADelimiter: Char): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(SerialEdits) - 1 do
    Result := Result + SerialEdits[I].Text + ADelimiter;
  if GetArrayLength(SerialEdits) > 1 then
  begin
    Delete(Result, Length(Result), 1);
  end
end;
```

Within another function below, I have a variable named `Serial: string`, but when I do

```
Serial := GetSerialNumber('');
```

I get a type mismatch error, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the return value, but the argument.

The `''` is not a valid `char` literal. A `char` literal must be exactly one character long. The `''` is a `string`.

If you want to allow an empty delimiter, change the argument type to the `string`.